# How to inject custom service on startup in .NET Core 5

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-5.0

I want to read my data from database and control it, and I need to do this in the request pipeline at startup.

So I have to do dependency injection at startup.

This is my (DI)

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration,IAuthHelper authHelper)
{
        Configuration = configuration;
        AuthHelper = authHelper;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
public IAuthHelper AuthHelper;
```

I encounter this error

> An error occurred while starting the application.
> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Laboratory.Core.Services.Interfaces.IAuthHelper' while attempting to activate 'Laboratory.Startup'.

I used service like this

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    var siteDirectory = AuthHelper.GetSiteSetting().MediaPath;
    var fileServerOptions = new FileServerOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine
                (env.WebRootPath, $@"{siteDirectory}User Picture\")),
            RequestPath = "/ServerFiles"
        };

    app.UseFileServer(fileServerOptions);
}
```

This is my service

```
public class AuthHelper : IAuthHelper
{
    private readonly LaboratoryContext _context;
    private readonly IRazorPartialToStringRenderer _renderer;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext;
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;
   
    public AuthHelper(LaboratoryContext context, IRazorPartialToStringRenderer renderer, IHttpContextAccessor httpContext, IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        _context = context;
        _renderer = renderer;
        _httpContext = httpContext;
        _clientFactory = clientFactory;
    }

    public TableSiteSetting GetSiteSetting()
    {
        try
        {
            return _context.TableSiteSettings.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            return new TableSiteSetting() { StaticIp = "ServerConnectionError" };
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return new TableSiteSetting() { StaticIp = "ServerError" };
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Your service can't be injected in Startup constructor because it has not been added yet to the dependency injection container. But you can inject it to the Configure method.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IAuthHelper authHelper)
{
    ...
}
```

I assume you have already registered the service in ConfigureServices

```
services.AddSingleton<IAuthHelper, AuthHelper>(); // Or scoped/transient depends what your service does.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
I did this, it works fine on localhost.
But when I publish the project on the host or IIS, I encounter Http Error 500.30

Comment: Navigate to the root directory of the published application using CMD and run the application using the command `dotnet run (yourApplicationName).dll` and check what error appears in console.

Answer (score 0):

You can get dbcontext service in program.cs and do what ever you like to your database data.
for example I use this approach to seed my database:

```
var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();         


using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

    var context = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();

    await ApplicationDbContextSeed.SeedSampleDataAsync(context)
}
            

host.Run();
```